# order to load code in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, row

i have the next code

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("a").on('click',function()
    {
      console.log("foo");
    });
```

and this code, generate a rows from database, and put the data on tbody

```
$.getJSON('file.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index) {
            $('#my_table > tbody').append(''
                        +"<tr id= "+data[index].id_marca_c+">"
                         +"<td>"
                           +"<a href='#'><i class='icon-pencil'></i></a> "
                         +'</td>'
                        +'</tr>');
        });
```

but in the function click on link not works in table generated for javascript, but if in html code.

example:

```
<html>
 <!-- /code -->
  <a href='#'><i class='icon-pencil'></i></a>  <!-- /this-works -->
</html>
```

but in the table generated for javascript, the function not works.
i revised the code generated, and it's ok.

EDIT:
the javascript code http://pastebin.com/2GZ4J28Q

Comment: @Rogue Click event is not added to dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delegated events for binding events with elements which are not present at binding time and added dynamically. You can delegate the event to parent of dynamically added elements or docuemnt.

```
$("#my_table").on('click',"a" ,function()
{
  console.log("foo");
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: It would be better if it was `$("#my_table > tbody").on('click',"a",...` Your answer `$(document)...` will be applied to every link on the entire page.